# ¿Como hacer un boton redondo con una imagen dentro de un sprite?

Tags: html, css

[image: EJEMPLO]

Me gustaria poder crear un menu con botones como este. La idea es utilizar usar imágenes de un sprite.

¿Como podría añadirle a la imagen del sprite el fondo redondo de color?

Ya he encontrado la solución. Os dejo el codigo para quien le sirva.

Este será el boton en **HTML**:

```
<div class="boton"><a class="burguer" href="#"></a></div>
```

Luego el **estilo** será el siguiente:

```
.boton{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#03800b;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float:left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.boton:hover{
  opacity: 0.50;
  -moz-opacity: .50;
  filter:alpha (opacity=50);
}
```

Con eso tenemos un circulo con el fondo verde.

Ahora nos queda añadirle dentro la imagen que proviene de un **sprite**:

```
.boton .burguer{
      width: 32px; height: 32px;
    background: url('/sprites1.png') -10px -10px;
       margin-top: 10px;
       text-align: center;
           display: inline-block;
                margin:0px auto;

}
```

Y de esta forma, tenemos un botón usando una imagen de un sprite.

Comment: Añade el código que tengas hasta ahora

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Si, ya he añadido el codigo. El codigo es el final, ya que dando vueltas saque el resutado final.

Answer (score 2):

**Creando un botón**

Puedes crear un `<div>`, darle un `border-radius` y ponerle un color de fondo con CSS, ponle un `float` si no va a tener posición fija

```css
.sprite {
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/hamburger.png" height="75" width="75">
</div>
```

**Añadiendo el menú**

Puedes hacerlo con JavaScript y un `transform` para añadirle animación

Al expandir el menú, le quitaremos el `border-radius` para prevenir que se vea raro

Cuando se haga click en el botón para expandir el menú, se quitará el `border-radius` y se expandirá el menú

```js
document.querySelector(".sprite > img").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const el = document.querySelector(".sprite > .menu");
  if (el.getAttribute("style")) {
    el.removeAttribute("style");
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector(".sprite").removeAttribute("style");
    }, 300);
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".sprite").style.borderRadius = "0";      
    el.style.transform = "scale(1,1)";
    el.style.position = "relative";
  }
});
```

```css
.sprite {
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:fixed;
}

.menu {
  background:blue;
  transform:scale(1,0);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1,0);
  -moz-transform:scale(1,0);
  -o-transform:scale(1,0);
  position:absolute;
  transition:0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:0.3s;
  -moz-transition:0.3s;
  -o-transition:0.3s;
  transform-origin:top center;
  -webkit-transform-origin:top center;
  -moz-transform-origin:top center;
  -o-transform-origin:top center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/hamburger.png" height="75" width="75">
  <div class="menu">
    <p><img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/hamburger.png" height="75" width="75"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, resuelve lo del círculo, pero sería bueno poner un ejemplo usando [sprites](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=742:sprite-css-concepto-ique-es-como-crear-y-usar-un-sprite-ejemplos-y-codigo-ejercicio-resuelto-cu01037d&catid=75&Itemid=203). +1